# Binary Semaphore with fetch and set function

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore

I am reading a blog from where I've found this below question :

> The atomic fetch-and-set x, y instruction unconditionally sets the 
>   memory location x to 1 and fetches the old value of x n y without 
>   allowing any intervening access to the memory location x. Consider the
>   following implementation of P and V functions on a binary semaphore S.

```
 void P (binary_semaphore *s) { 
     unsigned y; 
     unsigned *x = &(s->value); 
     do { 
         fetch-and-set x, y; 
     } while (y);  }

 void V (binary_semaphore *s) { 
     S->value = 0;  }
```

Which one of the following is true?

(A) The implementation may not work if context switching is disabled
 in P
 (B) Instead of using fetch-and –set, a pair of normal
 load/store can be used
(C) The implementation of V is wrong
(D)The code does not implement a binary semaphore

Answer given is : A

I've understood why option B is wrong.

Regarding Option C, by the definition of V (SIGNAL)it should increment the value of semaphore but in the function it just updates the semaphore value to 0.

The P (WAIT) function updates Semaphore value to 1 but isn't it supposed to decrease the value.

For Option D, I do agree that it is a Binary Semaphore but the P & V function implementations were reversed. ( Correct me If i'm wrong )

Are the P & V functions given in the program are same as Wait and Signal or they're just random function names?

What will be the value of 'y' when Fetch and Set runs for the first time?

Comment: According to C, `V()` is wrong. Since in `P()` `&s->value` is assigned to a `unsigned *` without a cast, `s->value` cannot be `_Atomic`, so `s->value = 0;` in `V()` is not an ordered atomic access. (Whether `fetch-and-set` is atomic is unclear from this snippet, as it's not even syntactically correct).

Comment: @EOF : This is just a sample snippet to test the Semaphore understanding not the actual implementation.
Considering that, does V() implementation is still correct?

Comment: We've established that the code is not correct C syntactically, nor is it well-defined even is we make considerable allowances for pseudocode. If you were to learn anything from it, it would be to incorrectly rely on guarantees given by particular implementations, where neither the compiler nor the processor reorder non-atomic memory accesses. The implementation is as far from correct as can be.